# How do I select multiple nested classes with css?

Tags: css

Is this what the css selector would do for the following div section?

```
.grid-row .col-6 {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

html:

```
<div class="grid-row">
    <div class="col-6">
        blah<br/>blah2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you go to JSFiddle, you can test things like this. http://jsfiddle.net/ :)

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me at all. However I guess you're looking for `.grid-row .col-6`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for confirmation of whether a (presented) selector will work with (presented) HTML. That's what 'testing' is for, if it doesn't work? *Then* come back and ask us about why (assuming it's not obvious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For nested selectors you must use a [**descendant selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) that is given by a white space:

*This targets the nested element at any hierarchy level*

```
.grid-row .col-6
{
   font-weight: bold
}
```

or you can use a [**child selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) that is given by a `>` sign:

*This targets only the direct child of an element*

```
.grid-row > .col-6
{
   font-weight: bold
}
```